# Reversing list using slicing method

Tags: python

Suppose `a=[1,2,3,4,5]`. If we write `a[len(a):-1:-1]`, following the slicing rule `[start:end:step size]`, why do we get an empty list? However, `a[len(a)::-1]` returns an reversed list `[5,4,3,2,1]`.

Please give me an explanation.

Comment: Because if you start at `len(a)` (beyond the end of the list) and end at `-1` (the last item in the list) going `-1` (backwards), there are no elements to include in the result.

Comment: So, your stop could be `0`, the beginning of the list, but since the stop is non-inclusive, it would omit the first element `1`! you tried to use `-1`. But that is actually the last element of the list! So you have to actually use `None`, e.g. `[len(a):None:-1]` . But the idiomatic way is just `[::-1]` which is equivalent to `[None:None: -1]`